# Built-in precedence for Expression Trees?

Tags: .net-3.5, expression-trees

I'm unable to find the .NET FCL built-in concept of precedence to leverage while constructing [Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx). Ref [System.Linq.Expressions Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.aspx). Is this something that must be handled manually in code, or is it somehow implicit and I'm not recognizing it, maybe through helper methods or classes?

I want to apply it to math operations to ensure 3 + 5 * 10 results in 53 instead of 80.

Comment: I would think (but I don't know, hence a comment and not an answer) that there is no precedence handling in expression trees, because the tree doesn't really leave any wiggle-room for this. For instance, if you write code to convert `a+b*c` into an expression-tree, and do it correctly, the tree will look like: `a+<expression1>` where `expression1` would be `b*c`, and there really is no way that this could evaluate any other way than the one you emitted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *whole point* of representing code as a tree is that the precedence is encoded in the tree structure itself, so that you do not need to care about it.

Comment: If anybody knows of helper classes to encode the tree accordingly to recommended precedence rules, within the FCL, then I'll be that much further ahead.